# I don't know why the end brackets and semicolons. It keeps showing red. I'm sure I have the code right

Tags: javascript

I cant get my JS project for school to work. I even googled it and it showed the same syntax. Can it be an html problem?

Google, Stackoverflow

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){

  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";

});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){

  document.getElementById("box").body.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";

});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){

  document.getElementById("box").body.style.backgroundColor = "opaque";

});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){

  document.getElementById("box").animate({height:"150px", width="150px", background-color="orange|initial", margin="25px" }, "fast");

});
```

It just shows the html, but the js does not work.

Comment: is it inside <script>?

Comment: where did you plzce the JS part before or after the html body part ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("box").body` is wrong. it just needs to be `document.getElementById("box")`

Comment: I placed the js part in the body of the html

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be this line:

```
document.getElementById("box").animate({height:"150px", width="150px", background-
color="orange|initial", margin="25px" }, "fast");
```

.animate receives an object, so margin=, width=, background-
color=, its not valid syntax, they should be followed by `:` `width:`